# How to export each subarrays as an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

is it possible that, get arrays to $value with key:
Example:

```
$array = Array("one"=>Array("field1"=>"value1","field2"=>"value2"),
"two"=>Array("field3"=>"value3","field4"=>"value4"));

Export arrays to value:

$first = any_main_php_function_name(0,$array);
$second = any_main_php_function_name(1,$array);

Result:
$first = Array("field1"=>"value1","field2"=>"value2");
$second = Array("field3"=>"value3","field4"=>"value4");
```

Basically, I wanna extract multiple array. If there is no such function (any_main_php_function_name) in PHP so How can i extract above $array.

Comment: You want to get each subarray an put it in an array with key as name ? Or transform multi array in simple array?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any funtion to do that. Simply get subarrays like this:

```
$first = $array['one'];
$second = $array['two'];
```

Unless you don't know the `one,two` keys, then you can use `array_shift` to get first item (`one` subarray). Remember that this functions also removes returned value from root array.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to get the element from array, Like this:

```
$first_element=array_shift($array);
```

> Make sure it only **removes** the **first** element from the array and
>   return the value of removed element.

---

And if you don't want to remove the element or get the sub-array in any sequence, then you can create a function like this,

```
function myFunction($index,$array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $sub_array=$arr[$keys[$index]];
}
```

In above function we just get the keys in a array and then use the known index to get the sub-array using keys array.

Answer (score 1):

array_slice does what you want

```
$first = array_slice($array, 0, 1);
$second = array_slice($array, 1, 1);

print_r($first);
print_r($second);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

foreach($array["one"] as $key=>$val){

```
echo "key=>".$key." Values=>".$val;
```

}

foreach($array["true"] as $key=>$val){

```
echo "key=>".$key." Values=>".$val;
```

}